# Cant make slippage work with custom linking in uniswap?

Tags: uniswap

Im using this format as an example

https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap?exactField=slippage=500&outputCurrency=0x8686525d6627a25c68de82c228448f43c97999f2

Slippage wont be input automatically, does anyone know why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.